# Mysql query output blank for one date and works for another date

Tags: mysql

Hi Below are the details.

**Mysql Table Table Structure**

## Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default

1   interval_start Primary  datetime            No  None
2   ad_id Primary   mediumint(9)            No  None
3   zone_id Primary     mediumint(9)            No  None
4   c_count     int(11)             No  0
5   i_count     int(11)             No  0
6   conversion_count    int(11)             No  None

Data inside the table

```
2020-10-08 09:30:00     216     10008   1   1   0
2020-10-08 10:30:00     216     10008   0   12  0
2020-10-08 10:32:17     216     10008   0   0   1
2020-10-08 10:40:39     216     10008   0   0   2
2020-10-08 13:30:00     216     10008   0   1   0
2020-10-09 09:30:00     216     10008   1   5   0
2020-10-09 10:10:38     216     10008   0   0   1
2020-10-09 10:30:00     216     10008   0   72  0
2020-10-09 10:56:02     216     10008   0   0   15
```

Mysql Query
**Output gives proper**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(i_count),
        DATE(interval_start) as date_time
    FROM
        rv_data_reports s
) e
where date_time = '2020-10-08';
```

**but for below query it renders blank output.**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(i_count),
        DATE(interval_start) as date_time
    FROM
        rv_data_reports s
) e
where date_time = '2020-10-09';
```

Comment: The sub query sums over the whole dataset but without a group by the date_time returned is indeterminate.

Comment: I just want to sum one column as mentioned and working well. Query  is not working for 2020-10-09 date record but working well for 2020-10-08 date records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub query sums over the whole dataset but without a group by the date_time returned is non determinate and actually your first query returns an incorrect sum for the date.

You don't say what you want the sub query to do but if you want to sum by date you should include a group by for example

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(i_count),
        DATE(interval_start) as date_time
    FROM
        T s
        GROUP BY DATE(interval_start)
) e
where date_time = '2020-10-08';
```

The sub query now returns the sums for both dates.
The query is clumsy you could use a having clause instead of a main query for example

```
   SELECT
        SUM(i_count),
        DATE(interval_start) as date_time
    FROM
        T s
        GROUP BY DATE(interval_start) having date_time = '2020-10-08'
```

If you want to sum for a specified data use a where clause

```
SELECT
        SUM(i_count),
        DATE(interval_start) as date_time
    FROM
        T s
        where DATE(interval_start) = '2020-10-08'
```

Comment: Dear Salmon,
query i have mentioned is not working for 2020-10-09 date record. and working well for 08 date records.
Records i need is mentioned in question, i dont want to sum other columns just one mentioned in query

Comment: Dear Salmon, i am using mysql 5.7 and working well in it.

Comment: returning  a sum of 91 for '2020-10-08' is clearly wrong..

Comment: ok, could you help me to solve the query with what it shall work well for all date records like 08 and 09 date.

Comment: All in the answer provided.

Comment: Hi, Actually there is another queries in which it is subquery so I do not want to use group by because it is throwing an error with it.

Comment: As your answer helped me, I am accepting it :)
Cheers (y)